# WSL2 is installed but won't launch

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I don't remember exactly how I installed WSL, but I think it installed with Docker.

When I run `wsl -l`, Docker appears in the list of WSL distributions.

But when I run the `wsl` command from the Windows Start menu, the window just opens and then closes immediately.

Comment: There are currently a few close votes as "Needs clarity".  I'm fairly confident that I know what you are asking, so I've edited it to attempt to improve the clarity for others.  Feel free to edit again if there's anything I got wrong.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds ok thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed WSL purely for Docker, then you likely have no "user" distribution installed.  Go to PowerShell and run:

```
wsl -l -v
```

This will display a list of installed distributions.  You most likely only have two:

```
NAME                   STATE           VERSION
docker-desktop         Stopped         2
docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
```

You can install a WSL distribution from the Microsoft Store (and several other methods).  I'd recommend Ubuntu for starters, as it is the default and most common.

While Ubuntu 22.04 (the latest long-term-support release) was released this week, I'd probably recommend 20.04 for now, since you'll probably find more information online for the moment around it.

Or you can go ahead and jump to the latest -- Your call, of course.

After installing a distribution, you'll likely need to go into the next steps regardless ...

Note that if you *do* have another distribution showing as installed, it may be that one of the Docker distributions is set as the "default".  If one of them has an asterisk next to it:

```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  Ubuntu                 Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
```

Then try:

```
wsl --set-default Ubuntu
# Or the name of your installed distribution
```